# Specifying the schema at time of creating connection in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I need to specify the schema name at time of connection creation in JDBC. How can i pass the schema as a parameter while creating a connection to jdbc

Comment: what did you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by the "schema"?  Do you mean the tables, columns etc?  You can't do that; you create those with SQL commands.

Comment: I want to create a table or perform a modification on table present in the specific schema .For instance if you check postgres db , the query is mentioned in server as select * from sachema.table_name. I tried working with <code>statment.execute(schema) </code>but that does'nt work for me

Comment: Which database system are you using? Is calling [`Connection.setSchema`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setSchema-java.lang.String-) ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify schema while connecting to a `database` as schema is specific to a `table` whereas connection links your application to a `database` (i.e. collection of tables).

If you want to connect to a specific database of server then you can specify it in connection string. Below is an example for MySQL:

```
jdbc:mysql://host:port/my_database?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&otherparam
```

It will connect to `my_database`.

Comment: At runtime how can I pass schema in  jdbc:mysql://host:port/my_databaseuseUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&otherparam

Comment: That's that the answer says, you **can't** pass the schema.